# compare new inserted value between two table in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, database-administration

Actually I need to compare newly inserted value between 2 tables in MySQL trigger .How should I do ?

For example, I have tableA & tableB and both having same table structure. If any insert comes to tableC then that new.id from tableC should compare with tableA and tableB and later it should update the value from corresponding table(there is no chance that id is present in both the tables, it will be present in either of one table).I need help in writing this in trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr
AFTER INSERT 
ON tableC
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE tableA SET tableA.val = NEW.val WHERE tableA.id = NEW.id;
    UPDATE tableB SET tableB.val = NEW.val WHERE tableB.id = NEW.id;
END
```

If a table (`tableA` or `tableB`) contains the value then according (otherwise - none) row(s) will be updated.

---

> the update table will be different. for example if `new.id` value found in `tableA` then `update xyz set xyz.val='tablea.val' where id=new.id`

No problems. Update query will be

```
UPDATE xyz
JOIN tableA ON xyz.id = tableA.id
SET xyz.val = tableA.val 
WHERE tableA.id = NEW.id;
```

Pay attention - `tableA.val` is the value of column `val` in table `tableA` whereas `'tableA.val'` is common string literal with specified value which refers to none.

Comment: the update table will be different. for example if new.id value found in tableA then update xyz set xyz.val='tablea.val' where id=new.id

Comment: @Kulal Updated.